# Pandas aggregating on all columns

Tags: python, pandas

Python 3 and pandas 0.23

I have a DataFrame with 2000 columns and need to do some variable elimination based on some summary statistics for each column.

Test data:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': np.random.normal(0, 2, 10), \
    'b': np.random.normal(0, 2, 10), \
    'c': np.random.normal(0, 2, 10) \
    })
```

Works:

```
data.aggregate(['min','max', 'nunique']).transpose()
```

Works, but how do I name the lambda column?

```
data.aggregate(['min','max', 'nunique', (lambda x: np.unique(x).size / x.size)]).transpose()
```

Apparently you're supposed to be able to give a dict to the aggregate function, but I can't get it working, except naming out all the columns for which to calculate the statistics, which is 2000 columns.

I wan't the resulting DataFrame in the format of a column for each min, max, nunqiue and a row for each column in the original `data` DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just `rename` the `<lambda>` column after the aggregation, but if you have multiple lambda functions then they all have the same name, and that's a problem. Instead, just define your functions with the name you want, and then call them in the `agg`.

```
import numpy as np

def named_f1(x):
    return np.unique(x).size / x.size

data.aggregate(['min','max', 'nunique', named_f1]).T
```

#### Output:

```
        min       max  nunique  named_f1
a -4.152149  4.095229     10.0       1.0
b -3.436940  3.266958     10.0       1.0
c -1.703651  3.198662     10.0       1.0
```

Comment: Not perfect, but i guess it will have to do. Thank you.